# "Error in file" help (upgrade)

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 1.6.2.0 to 1.9.3.4, and got this error:

```
Error in file: "/www/clonsite/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/data/sales_setup/data-upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main.base_tax_refunded' in 'field list', query was: UPDATE `sales_flat_order_item` AS `main`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(citem.row_total) AS `amount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_row_total) AS `base_amount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_tax_amount) AS `base_tax_refunded`, SUM(citem.discount_amount) AS `discount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_discount_amount) AS `base_discount_refunded`, `oitem`.`item_id` FROM `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AS `citem`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_creditmemo` AS `c` ON c.entity_id = citem.parent_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `o` ON o.entity_id = c.order_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `oitem` ON oitem.order_id = o.entity_id AND oitem.product_id=citem.product_id GROUP BY `oitem`.`item_id`) AS `selected`
SET `main`.`amount_refunded` = `selected`.`amount_refunded`, `main`.`base_amount_refunded` = `selected`.`base_amount_refunded`, `main`.`base_tax_refunded` = `selected`.`base_tax_refunded`, `main`.`discount_refunded` = `selected`.`discount_refunded`, `main`.`base_discount_refunded` = `selected`.`base_discount_refunded`
WHERE (main.item_id = selected.item_id)
```

I don't understand the meaning. Should I create some table to leave this error behind? Whch one and how?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**base_tax_refunded** column is missing in **sales_flat_order_item** table. So create **base_tax_refunded** column in **sales_flat_order_item** table. Clear cache.

Comment: Did that and it kept asking for more columns. I decided to remove the problematic database, imported the old working one, re-uploaded 1.9 files, removed all cache in /vars via FTP, and went to the admin: the upgrading scripts worked this time, no errors were shown, and the install is working now. I'll give the answer as good because it answers what happened and suggests a reasonable fix.